# Extension of a continuously differentiable function

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let $f:[0,+\infty)\times[0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^1$.

Can we find a function $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^1$ such that
$$F(t,x)=f(t,x), \quad \forall (t,x) \in [0,+\infty)\times[0,1].$$
If so, can we construct $F$ explicitly (as in the one-dimensional case) ?

My definition of a function $f$ of class $C^1$ on the closure of an open set is the following. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open subset and let $f:\Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We say that $f\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ if $f \in C^1(\Omega)$ and if there exists $f_0,f_1,f_2 \in C^0(\overline{\Omega})$ such that:
$$f(t,x)=f_0(t,x), \quad \partial_t f(t,x)=f_1(t,x), \quad \partial_x f(t,x)=f_2(t,x), \quad \forall (t,x) \in \Omega.$$

Comment: You could try to define $F(t,x) = 0, \forall t \in (-\infty , 0)$. Have you tried?

Comment: You mean to define $F(t,\cdot)$ for $t \in (-\infty,0)$ I guess ?
Mimicking the one-dimensional case, I would set $F(t,x)=f(0,x)+t \partial_t f(0,x)$ but the last term is not $C^1$ in $x$.